# How to use functions writen in C# rider, in Pycharm Python

Tags: c#, python, pycharm, rider

I'm new to programming and an intern, and they are asking me to convert their `python` code to `c#` (I've never programmed in c# before, please forgive any c# mistakes I made).

I'm trying to change some functions in `Python` to `C#` then call those C# function in Pycharm to increase the speed of Python. I'm trying to call the function itself, not through .Net or IronPython.

I found an example online that uses Unmanaged Exports, and tried using that but I get

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

C# code:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using RGiesecke.DllExport;

 class Test
 {
     [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
     public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
     {
         return left + right;
     }
 }
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Users\Family PC\RiderProjects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs")
a.add(3, 5)
```

I expected to get 8, when I call a.add(3,5). I'm using python 64 bit, pycharm 64, and rider 64.

Is there any way to do this, or am I trying in vain?

Comment: It sound that your C# Project needs to be 32 bit

Maybe it helps

Comment: Nowadays, I'm not so sure c# code is much faster than python for most uses. Are you sure this is worthwhile? I mean c# can be much faster but only for certain calculations, and only under certain environments. Since you're new to programming, I doubt you would be able to leverage these differences properly.